# How so I change the text of a link when it's clicked on using AJAX in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a link with the title of `Add to collection`. When the users clicks the link, I was AJAX to do some stuff in a function, and then change the link to say `Remove from collection`. Clicking it again would change it back to `Add to collection`.

What code do I need to write on the link itself to make the link perform this way?

```
<a onclick="myfunction();" href="whatdoiputhere.html">Add to collection</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="manage-collection">Add to collection</a>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('.manage-collection').on('click', function () {
        var $a = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_url',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { some: 'data' }
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.inCollection) {
                $a.text('Remove from collection');
            } else {
                $a.text('Add to collection');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the AJAX call was a success, and make a callback function that will change the title.

Not sure if you want an AJAX call for the second ('remove') click, but it's the similar procedure. You can need to check the state of the button, either via a variable, or the link title.

Edit

Just saw your update. You don't need a href attribute to make it work with AJAX (you can put a hash if you wish). In fact, it doesn't even need to be an anchor. The onclick function is enough.